# asp.net change content according to query string

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I want to create an asp.net web forms website that has a products page. I want to create a `products.aspx` page that has a specific layout and there I want to demonstrate the products. So in the url I will have something like `www.mysite.gr/products.aspx?productid=1` In other words I want to display different content according to the id from the query string parameter. Please can you propose me some ways to do this and also if you know provide some links that I can study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your site is laid out and how your project is built, there are various ways to approach this. For example, you can get the value of the QueryString like this:

```
string prodID = Request.QueryString["productid"];
if (prodID  != null)
{
    //perform database request passing the productid
    selectedProduct =  GetProductData(prodID);

}
```

Then, as a simple example, you can add the relevant details. For example, lets say you've got a product class from your `GetProdutData()` method. You can then fill out the elements on your page with the relevant data.

```
titleLabel.Text = selectedProduct.Title;
descriptionLabel.Text = selectedProduct.Decription;
image.ImageUrl = selectedProduct.ImageURL;
```

This is just one approach and there are various others, such as using the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.